# Prevent character or word auto-corrections in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, autocomplete, autocorrect

Is there a way to prevent Microsoft Word 2010 from making any auto-corrections.

Here's one example, that causes issues when creating technical documentation for server build scripts.  Copy and Pasting the auto-corrected hyphen causes the command to not run correctly.

If you type `./CA -sign`, the "-" (hyphen) changes to a "-" (dash) UNICODE character.  Pasting into a Putty.exe (Linux emulator session) will cause an error.  It's easy to tell if the hyphen changes.  It gets wider if using the default font in Word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Copy/Pasting an auto-corrected hyphen causes script errors

You can disable this particular auto-correction using the instructions below.

Note:

- As your issue is command line errors when using copy/paste into scripts you might want to consider also disabling the auto-correction of normal double quotes into smart quotes as well, as these will also cause problems.
- That can be disabled in the same "AutoCorrect" dialog.

---

#### Turn off auto replace of hyphens with dashes in Word 2010

> **Turn off hyphens with dash feature**
>
> Users can turn off the auto replacement of hyphens with dashes using
>   the option available as part of AutoCorrect settings. Click the File
>   menu –> Options link and navigate to Proofing Option screen then click
>   the AutoCorrect Options button in the Proofing screen.
>
> [image]
>
> In the AutoCorrect window, click the AuoFormat As You Type tab and
>   navigate to Replace as you type section.
>
> [image]
>
> Now unmark the check box with label as Hyphens (–) with dash (—) and
>   click OK button to confirm and save the changes.

Source [Turn off auto replace of hyphens with dashes in Word 2010](http://blogmines.com/blog/turn-off-auto-replace-of-hyphens-with-dashes-in-word-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

An old entry, but this is how you'd fix on web based MS Office:

Editor -> AutoCorrect Options.. -> unselect "Replace hyphens with dash"

[image]